# Partial object culling without alpha + transparency?

Tags: unity

I am trying to partially cull an object which has subsurface scattering.  It's simple to do it with an alpha channel, however, using an alpha channel with transparency will disable subsurface scattering.

Potentially relevant information: I am using Unity 2018.3.0b12 with v4.8.0-preview HDRP

Example: here I am achieving the effect with alpha + transparency. The object is either fully opaque or invisible

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this doesn't **technically** answer the question as this solution involves alpha clipping, I found out that you are able to do culling with "alpha clipping" while keeping surface type set to "opaque" instead of "transparent".

This solved the motivation behind me posting this StackExchange post. I don't have an answer for those looking for other ways to do partial culling without alpha and transparency.

Anyways, I did this by opening up the shader graph and editing the master node, as shown:
[image]